# Maya exported json file not able to play animation and display multiple texture with three.js

Tags: javascript, json, three.js, maya

I am working with **three.js (latest version r82)** and want to display **maya 2016 exported json models** on webpage.

I have tried **MultiMaterial as suggested by @mrdoob**, but it just shows blank (black) screen. 
First I thought it might be problem with camera (z position) but i was wrong, because when i am using **MeshNormalMaterial** then it is showing part I image. When i am using **MultiMaterial** then it is showing black screen (part II image).

Even it is not playing any animation, getting error Cannot read property '0' of undefined, because it is not getting any animation array but it is available in json file.

**Here it is my full code:**

```
        // common global variables for displaying file
        var container, controls, effect, clock;
        var camera, scene, renderer, tween;
        var manager, onProgress, onError;
        var ambient, directionalLight, hemisphereLight;
        var animation_array = [];
        var jsonFileName = 'assets/New-Heart/new-heart.json';

        init();

        function init() {
            // get div to draw canvas
            container = document.getElementById('3d-object-preview');

            // camera
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(30, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 10000);
            camera.position.set(0, 0, 100);
            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            camera.lookAt(scene.position);

            // ambient light
            ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 1);
            scene.add(ambient);

            //loading manager
            manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
            clock = new THREE.Clock();
            manager.onProgress = function (item, loaded, total) {
                console.log(item, loaded, total);
            };

            // jsonloader
            var jsonloader = new THREE.JSONLoader(manager);
            jsonloader.load(jsonFileName, function (geometry, materials) {
                //mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial(materials));
                mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MultiMaterial(materials));
                scene.add(mesh);
                // even it is not playing any animation, getting error '0' is undefined
                var mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(mesh);
                animation_array.push(mixer);
                mixer.clipAction(geometry.animations[0]).play();
            }, onProgress, onError);

            /* Renderer */
            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
                antialias: true, // to get smoother output
                preserveDrawingBuffer: true // to allow screenshot
            });
            renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
            animate();
        }

        function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            if (animation_array.length > 0) {
                console.log('animation play....');
                for (var i = 0; i < animation_array.length; i++) {
                    animation_array[ i ].update(clock.getDelta());
                }
            }
            render();
        }

        function render() {
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        }
```

Here you can see my **json materials array**:

```
    "materials": [{
    "opacity": 0.0, 
    "mapDiffuseRepeat": [1, 1], 
    "mapNormalFactor": 1, 
    "depthTest": true, 
    "colorDiffuse": [0.5, 0.5, 0.5], 
    "vertexColors": false, 
    "blending": "NormalBlending", 
    "mapDiffuseAnisotropy": 4, 
    "shading": "Lambert", 
    "transparent": true, 
    "depthWrite": true, 
    "mapNormalRepeat": [1, 1], 
    "mapNormalWrap": ["repeat", "repeat"], 
    "DbgName": "Arota", 
    "mapNormalAnisotropy": 4, 
    "mapNormal": "Heart_Arota_NM.jpg", 
    "mapDiffuseWrap": ["repeat", "repeat"], 
    "mapDiffuse": "Heart_Arota_Diffuse.jpg"
}, {
    "opacity": 0.0, 
    "mapDiffuseRepeat": [1, 1], 
    "mapNormalFactor": 1, 
    "depthTest": true, 
    "colorDiffuse": [0.5, 0.5, 0.5], 
    "vertexColors": false, 
    "blending": "NormalBlending", 
    "mapDiffuseAnisotropy": 4, 
    "shading": "Lambert", 
    "transparent": true, 
    "depthWrite": true, 
    "mapNormalRepeat": [1, 1], 
    "mapNormalWrap": ["repeat", "repeat"], 
    "DbgName": "Full_Heart1", 
    "mapNormalAnisotropy": 4, 
    "mapNormal": "Full_Heart_NM.jpg", 
    "mapDiffuseWrap": ["repeat", "repeat"], 
    "mapDiffuse": "Full_Heart_Diffuse.jpg"
}]
```

Can anybody help me to fix this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Darryl_Lehmann can you please look here!

Comment: @WestLangley can you please look here!

Comment: @bhouston can you please look here!

Comment: @mrdoob can you please look here!

Comment: Referenced on git : https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/9997